# sed regular expression for date field

Tags: regex, sed

I have a log file where the date-time field format is [4/28/17 19:50:01:402 CDT]. I have been trying to use regular expression to factor in all the months and days of the year. 
The below format is working for me

```
sed -n '/^\[[1-9]\/28\/17 19:30/,/\[[1-9]\/28\/17 22:30/p'
```

However, when I try to refine it to consider all months  by introducing '|' , I am not getting the desired output.

```
sed -n '/^\[[1-9]|1[0-2]\/28\/17 19:30/,/\[[1-9]|1[0-2]\/28\/17 22:30/p'
```

Eventually, I plan to make this change for the date and year field as well. However, I am now stuck at the month field itself. What am I doing wrong?

Below is the complete line of the command

```
grep -i perfmon $1 | sed -n '/^\[[1-9]|1[0-2]\/28\/17 19:30/,/\[[1-9]|1[0-2]\/28\/17 22:30/p' $1 | awk '{print $11,$13}'| sed -e 's/ms//g' > PERFMON.log
```

Comment: Sed uses basic regular expressions, which don't include alternation (`|`). GNU sed supports them as an extension, but they have to be escaped: `\|`. BSD and GNU sed support extended regular expressions (which include `|`) with the `-E` option.

Comment: Which sed version are you using? Show output of `sed --version` With that info and the comment by @BenjaminW. somebody could give a detailed answer.

Comment: I am using GNU sed version 4.1.5
Copyright (C) 2003 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: I executed the following code incorporating the escape character.       
 grep -i perfmon $1 | sed -n '/^\[[1-9]\|1[0-2]\/1\/17 17:30/,/\[[1-9]\|1[0-2]\/1\/17 18:00/p' $1 | awk '{print $11,$13}'| sed -e 's/ms//g' > PERFMON.log         
                                                                                                             
                                                                                                          
 Now, I am getting results, but not for the specified time window. I am getting the results for the whole day.

Comment: Are you able to give an input and desired output example? If I try your working example `echo "[4/28/17 19:50:01:402 CDT]" | sed -n '/^\[[1-9]\/28\/17 19:30/,/\[[1-9]\/28\/17 22:30/p'` there is no result.